# ASP.Net MVC foreach conditional row style

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to conditionally set the row style of a table in MVC view.

Here is how I am building the table. You can see that I want to set the td style based a whether there is a personID in the attendances entity in the model.
When I debug I see the style being set but since the page does not refresh the styles don't appear until there is a manual refresh.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.People)
{
    int attendedPersonID = Model.Attendances.Where(a => a.PersonID == item.PersonID).Select(p => p.PersonID).SingleOrDefault();
    <tr>
        <td style="@(attendedPersonID == item.PersonID ? "color:green" : "color:red")"  >
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.PersonID)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button  value="@item.PersonID" class="present">Present</button>
            <button  value="@item.PersonID" class="absent">Absent</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Edit, I decided I don't want to reload the list of people each time the page is loaded so I am now using ajax to build the table. How do I find the jQuery selectors when the table is built with ajax?

```
 $.getJSON("/Attendance/People/", function(data) {
            var table='<table>';
            $.each( data, function( index, item){
                table+='<tr><td><input type=hidden id="personID" value='+item.personID+' /></td><td>'+item.FullName+'</td><td><button  value='+item.personID+' class="present">Present</button><button  value='+item.personID+' class="absent">Absent</button></td></tr>';       
            });
            table+='</table>';
            $("#table1").html( table );     
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In your model class add this method:

```
public bool IsInAttendedList(int personId)
{
    return this.Attendances.Where(a => a.PersonID == personID).FirstOrDefault() !== null;
}
```

CSS:
.red { color: #FF0000;}
.green { color: #00FF00;}

In your cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.People)
{
    <tr class="item">
        <td class="person @(Model.IsInAttendedList(item.PersonID) ? "green" : "red");">
            <input type="hidden" name="PersonID" value="@item.PersonID" /> @item.FullName
        </td>
        <td>
            <button value="@item.PersonID" class="action present">Present</button>
            <button value="@item.PersonID" class="action absent">Absent</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

the use of `HiddenFor` and `DisplayFor` is wrong, because you have to use the model for this, plus you have to have different attr `id` for each case or not use the `id`.

**edit for comment**

I add the class for get tr elements. You can send data to server like this:

```
$('.item').each(function(i, el) {


    var tr = $(this);
    tr.find('.action').bind('click', function(event) {

       var type = $(this).hasClass('present') ? 'present' : 'absent';
       $.post('URL', {personID: $(this).val(), typeAction= type })
          .done(function() { 

              var class = type == 'present' ? 'green' : 'red';
              tr.find('.person').removeClass('green red').addClass(class);
           })
          .fail(function() { 

           });
    });

});
```

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: @user810388 Can you put the html render?

Comment: <tr>
 <td style="color:#FF0000;">
 <input type="hidden" name="PersonID" value="1" /> person1</td>
        <td>
            <button  value="1" class="present">Present</button>
            <button  value="1" class="absent">Absent</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td style="color:#00FF00;">
 <input type="hidden" name="PersonID" value="2" /> person2</td>
        <td>
            <button  value="2" class="present">Present</button>
            <button  value="2" class="absent">Absent</bu

Comment: Is the refresh issue because I am using ajax to post the data to the controller action? Do I need to refresh with jQuery after the post?

Comment: if you add in the list Attenderd the `tem.PersonID`, you need refresh de page or change the color for this tr

Comment: The color changes but you can't see the change unless you manually refresh the page. MVC and ajax is new to me so I don't know if I need to use jQuery to refresh the page after the ajax post.

Comment: Thanks. See my edit regarding building the table from json returned from ajax.

Comment: @user810388 ok, but continuing your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to use JSON to retrieve the values and build the table instead of binding the model to the view.

Comment: @user810388 ok, if it was helpful to solve the problem, you could select it as a solution or useful

Answer (score 0):

I am now building my table with JSON response like this:

```
$.getJSON("/Attendance/People/", function(data) {
            var table='<table>';
            $.each( data, function( index, item){
                table+='<tr><td class='+item.personID+'>'+item.FullName+'</td><td><button  value='+item.personID+' class="present">Present</button><button  value='+item.personID+' class="absent">Absent</button></td></tr>';       
            });
            table+='</table>';
            $('#table1').html(table);
```

I am setting the initial color of the td here:

```
$('td').each(function () { $(this).css('color', 'red') })
```

I am conditionaly setting a td back to green based on the attendance response:

```
 $.getJSON("/Attendance/Attendances/", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    $('td.' + item.returnedPersonID).css('color', 'green');
```